# reactjs leaflet kml wrong behaviour

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I'm using https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins display kml in my map, it work's great, but when I'm using reactjs kml not displaying as should be and `map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());` not working, there is no problem if not using reactjs, here is my code

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        mymap = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(-2.6025, 140.6927), zoom: 11});
        var baselayer = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'OSM ',
            maxZoom: 18,
        });

        mymap.addLayer(baselayer);

        baselayer.on('load', function (event) {
            var track = new L.KML("/files/1/Layer/Administrasi/Administrasi Kota Jayapura.kml", {async: true});
            mymap.addLayer(track);
        }); 
    }
```

here is the result when using reactJS

[image: here is the result when using reactJS]

[image: Not using ReactJS]

Do I Miss something ?

Comment: Any errors in the developer tools of your web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that KML was threaded as svg or not, but but global style for SVG seems affected KML as well, so remove/modify css for svg solve this problems.